# Makefile : Compiling a library in a subdirectory

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I want a makefile to compile a library (DRNG) with another makefile located in a subdirectory.

Here is what I have done :

```
.PHONY: out.exe clean drng

DRNG_DIR=./libdrng-1.0/

clean:
    make clean -C $(DRNG_DIR)
    @rm -f out.exe *.o

drng:
    cd $(DRNG_DIR) && ./configure
    make -C $(DRNG_DIR)

CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -std=c++11
LDFLAGS=-L$(DRNG_DIR) -ldrng
objects=...

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.cpp -o $*.o

out.exe: drng main.o $(objects)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

I get an error : `g++: drng: no such file or directory`
Make is trying to compile 'drng'. I thought putting it in PHONY was supposed to prevent that.

Comment: How do you invoke Make? What do you see in the output above the error message?

Comment: configure run fine and the library is compiled. After that, all the .o are compiled and when g++ is called like this : `g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 drng objects...`. With 'drng' as parameter, which obviously wail, but why make is passing 'drng' as parameter ?

Comment: `$^` means "all the dependencies of the rule".  Including `drng`.

Comment: I just figured it out. Thank you anyway

Comment: You can use `$(filter-out drng,$^)` if you don't want it.